# Get id from URL parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My project is using React 16.9^ with Hooks and I'm trying to get the parameter from the URL.

`http://localhost:3000/kontakt/confirm-account?token=d5b72ed2-ebb3-4da9-8619-1223234950a5`

**I need to detach the last part:**

`confirm-account?token=d5b72ed2-ebb3-4da9-8619-1223234950a5`

Whats the best practice to do this?
Any suggestions on how this could be done would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location.href.split('/').reverse()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example: [w3schools snippet](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9HOVXRMIOAB)

```js
var allUrl =  window.location.href
var result = window.location.href.split('/').reverse()[0]

document.getElementById("fullUrlId").innerHTML = "full url: " + allUrl ;
document.getElementById("resultId").innerHTML = "url after split: " + result;
```

```html
<div id= "fullUrlId"> url </div>
<div id= "resultId"> result </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the window.location and extract this part

```js
console.log(window.location)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the whole part after the last `/`?
Because you can get the `url` parameters (after `?`) easy with `window.location.search`
Otherwise you need a string manipulation function

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    console.log(urlParams.toString()); // this will log the part you need: urlParams.toString()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to do token based authentication system you can send token on every request header ***x-access-token*** and verify that on server side (middleware)

[image]